# Fedora CoreOS Offline Installation with USB

Tags: fedora, coreos, coreos-ignition

I have been assigned a task to evaluate Fedora CoreOS, I mostly install CentOS with KickStart file.

I searched a lot but couldn't find any source where i can customize Fedora CoreOS ISO file and add ignition file so on first boot it start installing rather than doing below

```
coreos-install -d /dev/sda -i ignition.json
```

I am looking for something similar to below

https://shawnliu.me/post/kickstart-centos-7-installation/

**Update1:**

- To install FCOS we need following two files,

  `fedora-coreos-30.20191014.0-installer.x86_64.iso`

  `fedora-coreos-30.20191014.0-metal.x86_64.raw.xz`
- From .iso we can boot and Once we reached the boot menu we press  (isolinux) to edit the kernel command line. Add the parameters to the kernel command line

  `coreos.inst.image_url=http://example.com/fedora-coreos-30.20191014.0-metal.x86_64.raw.xz`
- Now press  (isolinux) to kick off the install.
- As i want to do offline installation so i did following steps

  `mkdir -p ~/mnt/iso
  sudo mount -o loop fedora-coreos-30.20191014.0-installer.x86_64.iso ~/mnt/iso/
  rsync -av ~/mnt/iso/* ~/fcos_build/
  cd ~/aggreko_build/
  sudo umount ~/mnt/iso`
- fcos_build has folders {isolinux,images,EFI}
- I edit isolinux.cfg like below

  `label linux
    menu label ^Install Fedora CoreOS
    kernel /images/vmlinuz
    append initrd=/images/initramfs.img nomodeset rd.neednet=1 coreos.inst=yes coreos.inst.image_url=ftp:///images/fedora-coreos-30.20191014.0-metal.x86_64.raw.xz`
- copied the **fedora-coreos-30.20191014.0-metal.x86_64.raw.xz** in images directory
- CReate custome iso with below commands

  `mkisofs -o fcos-custom.iso -b isolinux.bin -c boot.cat -no-emul-boot -V "fcos-custom" -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -R -J -v -T .
  isohybrid fcos-custom.iso
  implantisomd5 fcos-custom.iso`

Now when i boot from this iso its unable to access fedora-coreos-30.20191014.0-metal.x86_64.raw.xz from images.

Comment: What is the target platform? Because in most cases you don't need the the ISO. It's definitely the least flexible out of all available options. Ideally you run (Fedora) CoreOS on a cloud platform and provide the ignition config for the initial boot through the cloud providers implementation of 'use-data', or use PXE boot for bare-metal and pull the ignition config from a http/tftp server.

Comment: I want to install on BareMetal, In Lab i can access PXE boot but for production i might have only one server available, so that why looking for full offline installation. We have to deploy on very remote sites for IOT stuff.

Comment: I would have to dive into this, but there is a separate installer-iso image that should be able to get an ignition config from an url on the boot prompt (see also https://github.com/coreos/coreos-installer/). To make it completely hand-off, I don't see why it wouldn't be possible to extract the ISO, add an ignition config, update the default grub config and create a new ISO image from that.

Comment: @basvdlei i did changes as you suggested(see update1 section in question) but no success yet